# Change remove cart item url in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, cart

My simple question is that how I can make this code working

```
esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
```

the above i have tried and the current code is below

```
 esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
```

so instead my current url : `example.com/?removed_item=1`

should be something like `example.com/cart/?removed_item=1`

Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

> `WC_Cart` `get_remove_url()` method is deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_cart_remove_url()` function.

It can be used as follow:

```
// Loop through cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Get the remove Url for the current cart item
    $remove_url = wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key );
}
```

this will give you an url like: `https://www.example.com/cart/?removed_item=1…`

---

Now to make changes on this Url, you can use `woocommerce_get_remove_url` dedicated filter hook, like in this example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_remove_url', 'custom_item_remove_url', 10, 1 );
function custom_item_remove_url( $remove_url ) {
    $cart_page_url   = wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );
    $replacement_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ); // Shop page

    // Change URL to shop page + remove Url query vars
    $remove_url = str_replace($cart_page_url, $replacement_url, $remove_url);

    return $remove_url;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

this will give you an url like: `https://www.example.com/shop/?removed_item=1…`

Comment: instead shop i want to redirect to cart and i have change into your code its not working

Comment: on my mini cart when i remove the cart item its not redirecting to view cart page this is the problem with your code the URL showing bottom but its not redirecting to view cart page

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj It's not possible to do it for minicart as there is no redirection and it's managed by ajax.

Comment: This code doesn't work unfortunately. "There has been a critical error on this website"

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_remove_url', 'custom_item_remove_url', 10, 1 );
function custom_item_remove_url( $remove_url ) {
    $cart_page_url   = wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );
    $replacement_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ); // Shop page

    // Change URL to shop page + remove Url query vars
    $remove_url = str_replace($cart_page_url, $replacement_url, $remove_url);

    return $remove_url;
}