# Change removing cart item url to checkout to avoid wrong checkout

Tags: php, wordpress

My simple question is that how I can make this code working

```
esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
```

the above i have tried and the current code is below

```
 esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
```

so instead my current url : example.com/?removed_item=1

should be something like example.com/checkout/?removed_item=1

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change remove cart item url in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451684/change-remove-cart-item-url-in-woocommerce)

Comment: That did not work unfortunately..

Comment: what exactly you tried?

Comment: So inserted the code into the functions.php, but unfortunately this generated a massive error: "a critical error has occured on your site."

Comment: Which code you inserted?

Comment: foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Get the remove Url for the current cart item
    $remove_url = wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_remove_url', 'custom_item_remove_url', 10, 1 );
function custom_item_remove_url( $remove_url ) {
    $cart_page_url   = wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );
    $replacement_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ); /Shoppage
    // Change URL to shop page + remove Url query vars
    $remove_url = str_replace($cart_page_url, $replacement_url, $remove_url);
    return $remove_url;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. code will goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_remove_url', 'change_item_remove_url_to_checkout', 10, 1 );
function change_item_remove_url_to_checkout( $remove_url ) {
    $cart_page_url   = wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );
    $replacement_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ); // Shop page
    $remove_url      = str_replace( $cart_page_url, $replacement_url, $remove_url );
    return $remove_url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately does not work (yet). However, no critical errors. Is it a problem that I have not set a cart because I want people to go directly to checkout?

Comment: Here is the site : yourubl.nl/product/essential

Comment: I tested in my local and working fine for me.

Comment: Okay, weird. My cart page is the checkout page because of direct checkout. Do you see that as a problem using this code?

Comment: Yes I saw that but need to debug more into this.

Comment: I can provide you with login details if you want

Comment: I will back to you.